# Setting a cookie with a button

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a program that autoplays music and saves the play time; when you're browsing around the website, it'll continue from the save point, not start over fresh.

I want to add a cookie so that when users press the "Music off" button, it'll not play again even if they refresh the page... And then vice versa, so if they put it on again it'll stay on even if they refresh.

I've spent hours on this, and I still can't figure it out...

This is what I have so far:

```
 <style>
#chatter {
padding: 10px;
background-image: url();
background-color: #B8B8B8;
border: 1px solid #d4d0d9;
position: fixed;
bottom: 35px;
right: 35px;
z-index: 100;
display: none;
}

#nav {
    line-height:1px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:25px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:3px; 
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 75px;
    left: 1550px;
}
#header-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#fixedcbox {
     position:fixed;
     bottom:0;
     right:0;
}

#fixeddb {
     position:fixed;
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
}
#clicker {
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<div id="fixedcbox">
<div id="clicker">
<input type ="button" id="player" value="Music: On" style="height:25px;width:100px" onclick="javascript:toggleSound();javascript:changeText;">

</button>
</div>
</div>
<audio id="audioToggle" preload="auto" src="http://se7en-ps.com/forums/public/Music/Christmas_song.mp3" loop="true" autobuffer>
</audio>

<script>

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
        {
        return unescape(y);
        }
      }
}

var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var played = false;
var tillPlayed = getCookie('timePlayed');
function update()
{
    if(!played){
        if(tillPlayed){
        song.currentTime = tillPlayed;
        song.play();
        played = true;
        }
        else {
                song.play();
                played = true;
        }
    }

    else {
    setCookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime);
    }
}
setInterval(update,1000);
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

function changeText()
{
 var value = document.getElementById("player").value;  
 if (value == "Music: On")
    document.getElementById("player").value = "Music: Off";
 else
    document.getElementById("player").value = "Music: On";
}
function toggleSound() {
  var audioElem = document.getElementById('audioToggle');
  if (audioElem.paused)
    audioElem.play();

  else
    audioElem.pause();
    changeText();

}
</script>
```